# Using か within a sentence

Tags: grammar, usage, particles

I want to make a question within a sentence using か, but it’s weird for me.

I don’t want to use か at the end of a sentence. もう知ってる

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand what you're question is. Can you give an example of the kind of sentence you're trying to make?

Comment: @user3856370 エミは夏休み中どこへ行くか知らない。

Comment: Okay, so why is that weird for you?

Comment: @user3856370 I’ve never done it before in Japanese

Comment: It's called an 'embedded question'. Try searching this site for that phrase. There's a lot of information about it.

Comment: @user3856370 thank you 

Comment: @Mindful yes it does I favorite it so I can read over it again.